# Direct evaluation challenge of a Dedekind $\eta$ elliptic integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, elliptic-integrals

I believe I have a *challenge* for the integration community.

> Show directly: $$2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(4ix)^6\eta(20ix)^6}{\eta(2ix)^2\eta(8ix)^2\eta(10ix)^2\eta(40ix)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varphi}}K\left(\frac{i}{\varphi}\right),$$ where $\varphi:=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

As a reminder, here $\eta(\tau):=q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-q^n\right)$ with $q:=e^{2\pi i\tau}$ is the Dedekind eta function with $\Im(\tau)>0$ and $K(k):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

---

What I mean by "show *directly*" is a method that does not utilise the fact that the integrand is the modular form associated with the elliptic curves in the isogeny class with Cremona label $80b$. In particular, it must not use the fact that these elliptic curves are of rank $0$ and thus have a general integral formula for their associated $L$-function at $s=1$ given by some rational factor multiplied by the integral of the associated Néron differential over $E\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ (which can, in general, be expressed in terms of $K$ and the roots of the cubic of the elliptic curve in simplified form, say).

I am after a direct approach that utilises, for example, substitutions that transform the integrand from being in terms of $\eta$ into being in terms of say $K,K',k,k'$ and evaluating the resulting integral(s) through standard integration techniques.

Comment: The integrand involves the eta functions of $q=e^{-4\pi x} $ as well that of $q^5=e^{-20\pi x} $. So converting the integrand in terms of corresponding elliptic modulus $k$ will also involve the modulus $l$ for $q^5$ and I doubt if a nice form of integrand would come out. The modular equations of degree $5$ would be needed. Perhaps a more interesting idea would be look at the ratios of eta functions and see if they can be represented as some Lambert series in terms of $q $.

Comment: Using Euler Function $\phi(q)$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1q^{-1/2}\phi^2(-q)\phi^2(-q^5)dq$$

Comment: [OEIS A159817](https://oeis.org/A159817) Coefficients of L-series for elliptic curve "80b2": $y^2 = x^3 - x^2 - x$.

$$\phi^2(-q)\phi^2(-q^5)=1+2q-q^2-2q^3+q^4+2q^6+...$$

Didn't find any Lambert Series.